# Unable to stop my Amazon RDS instance from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

**RDS:** my-sql

**What am I trying to achieve:** Trying to stop RDS instance through CLI.

**What command did I use:**

```
aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier test
```

**Error Message:**

```
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

**Does it work with other CLI commands:** Yes, I tried rebooting, listing the instances and events. It worked fine.

**Is it a Multi-AZ:** Yes, But I tried with a stand alone too. No luck.

**Is it a read replica:** No

Comment: what does it suggest are your other valid choices, based off the error message?  What version of aws cli are you using in your environment?

Comment: See my answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668305/stopping-an-rds-instance-via-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to Stop an Amazon RDS is quite new ([June 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/)). It is possible that your [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) it out-of-date.

You can update the AWS CLI with:

```
sudo pip install awscli --upgrade
```

Then, try the command again.

Comment: Thanks again John, I was little speculative on how a CLI upgrade could fix this issue, Coz i was able to run other commands. After upgrading the CLI, I was able to stop the Stand-alone RDS instance.The Multi-AZ, I could not and i know the reason for it. Thanks for your help.                                                                                     Regards, R